# Show that sum of independent but not identically distributed r.v. does not converge a.s.

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence, independence

Let $X_k$, $k\geq 1$, be independent with the following distribution: $P(X_k=\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}})=\frac12=P(X_k=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}})$. Define $S_n:=\sum_{k=1}^{n} X_k$. Show that $S_n$ does not converge a.s.

So far I have explored (without success) the following ideas: showing that $(S_n)_n$ is a.s. not a Cauchy sequence and looking at the limiting characteristic function.

Any other ideas? Or maybe followups to mine? Than you!

**Later edit:** Thank you for the ideas so far. Any other ones using less "heavy machinery" than Lindeberg-Feller or Kolmogorov's three series theorem?

Comment: It is probably overkill, but the Lindeberg version of the CLT should get you there

Comment: To the downvoter: why? This looks like an OK question to me (and the OP did specify some thoughts and attempts made).

Answer (score 2):

*With Kolmogorov's three-series theorem:*

Note that
$$\operatorname{var} X_k = \mathbb{E}[X_k^2] = \frac{1}{k}$$
and therefore
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty \operatorname{var} X_k = \infty\,.
$$
Therefore, condition (iii) of [Kolmogorov's three-series theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%27s_three-series_theorem) is violated: the series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty X_k$ does not converge almost surely.

Answer (score 1):

There is a martingale approach to Kolmogorov's three series theorem which can be invoked to produce a self-contained (modulo standard facts on martingales) proof for the current problem (see D. Williams, *Probability with Martingales*, chapter 12 for more details). So in a sense, what we present below is a fragment toward martingale proof of Kolmogorov's three series theorem.

Let $a_n^2 = Var(S_n)$, then it is straightforward to see (in view of the independence condition) that $M_n := S_n^2 - a_n^2 $ is a martingale (with respect to filtration $\mathcal{F}_n = \sigma(X_1,...,X_n)$).

Now assume for contradiction that $S_n$ converges almost surely. Then $S_n$ is bounded almost surely, and for some (large) constant $0<c<\infty$ we must have
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{P}(|S_n| \leq c \  \text{ for all } \ n \in \mathbb{N} )  > 0 . \tag{1}
\end{equation}

Consider the stopping time $T = \inf\{ n \in \mathbb{N}: \ |S_n| > c \}$. Since $M_n$ is a martingale, it follows that so is the stopped process $M_{n \wedge T}$, in particular $\mathbb{E} M_{n \wedge T} =0$, which gives
$$
\mathbb{E} a_{n\wedge T}^2 = \mathbb{E} S_{n\wedge T}^2.
$$
From here we get
\begin{equation}
a_n^2 \mathbb{P}(T = \infty) \leq \mathbb{E} a_{n\wedge T}^2 = \mathbb{E}( S_{n}^2   \mathbb{I}_{T = \infty}) + \mathbb{E}( S_{n\wedge T}^2   \mathbb{I}_{T  < \infty}) \leq c^2 + (c + 1)^2, \tag{2}
\end{equation}
where for the last inequality we used the fact that $|S_n| \leq c$ as long as $n \leq T$, and that $|S_T - S_{T-1} | = |X_T| \leq 1$.

Finally, observe that $(1)$ implies $\mathbb{P}(T = \infty) > 0$, which combined with $(2)$ shows that $a_n^2 $ is bounded above. This is a contradiction, as $a_n \sim \log n $, and the proof is complete.